# After deploy to azure, my app gets 404

Tags: html, azure, azure-web-app-service

I can run this locally just fine and while using angular, it is just localhost:3000/#/. Logging in via FTP to my azure site after deploy, the folder structure is like:

[image]

Comment: are you sure the `index.html` is not supposed to be at the `/site/wwwroot/` level (instead of inside the `src` folder)?

Comment: and what happens if you go to `http://<your-ip>:<port>/src/#/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your angularjs application including `index.html` is in the `src` folder in your entire project folder, under the path `site/wwwroot/` on Azure Web Apps. If so, it is a location issue.

As the root directory on Azure Web Apps is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, when you browse your site on Azure, it will find the entrance page or the iis configuration file in the root directory. And there is no such file in your application, which raises the issue.

You can simply set the `Virtual applications and directories` in the `Application Settings` on Azure portal(https://ms.portal.azure.com). Set `\` to `site\wwwroot\src`, save and restart your Web App. 
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Seems it changed, but still not rendering correctly. So now I go to: http://cembtest.azurewebsites.net/#/ as that opens the main page locally. Even if I go http://cembtest.azurewebsites.net/index.html, it still doesn't render. Even just simply cembtest.azurewebsite.net/ , nothing....

Comment: I haven't find any javascript scripts loaded on your site. Could you double check the combined angularjs script has been included in the correct path? Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The files/folders in your src folder need to be in the wwwroot folder. Doing say could mess up the references to any files under node_modules, so, depending on your IDE/tooling, you should probably publish the site to a local folder, which should pull in any necessary files and then upload the published folder structure.